# Hide login page after successful login and show main_activity in android

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, google-cloud-messaging, android-webview

I am new to android studio and I have created an app which has an Android webview using GCM notifications. The app has two activities:

1. activity_register (used for a new user to register with the app)
2. activity_main (used as a main screen of the app)

When I launch my app every time activity_register get displayed. I want to hide activity_register after first time the user logs in successfully.

1)activity_register [LOGIN WINDOW SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXNPs.png)

**AndroidMainfest.xml**

```
<application
    android:name="com.eduapp.Controller"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">




    <!-- Main Activity -->
    <activity
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:name="com.eduapp.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

    </activity>

    <!-- Register Activity -->
    <activity
        android:name="com.eduapp.RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="com.idrivecare.familypro" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;
Controller aController;


//----------------------------------------------------

private WebView webView;
private ProgressBar progress;
public Uri imageUri;

//-----------------------------------------------------


// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

public static String name;
public static String email;
//-------------------ON-CREATE-START-------------------
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //---------------------------------------------------------
    //web settings
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    //progress bar setting
    progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progress.setMax(100);

    //load page settings
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    // mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl("http://demo.eduapp.in/pages_admin");

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------

    //Get Global Controller Class object (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
    aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();


    // Check if Internet present
    if (!aController.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        // Internet Connection is not present
        aController.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Getting name, email from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("email");

    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest permissions was properly set
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

    // Register custom Broadcast receiver to show messages on activity
    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            Config.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {

        // Register with GCM
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);

    } else {

        // Device is already registered on GCM Server
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {

            // Skips registration.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already registered with GCM Server",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
                    show();

        } else {

            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.

            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    aController.register(context, name, email, regId);

                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };

            // execute AsyncTask
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);

        }




    }
}

//-------------------ON-CREATE-END-------------------

// Create a broadcast receiver to get message and show on screen
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());

        // Display message on the screen
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + " ");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Got Message: " + newMessage,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Releasing wake lock
        aController.releaseWakeLock();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // Cancel AsyncTask
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        // Unregister Broadcast Receiver
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);

        //Clear internal resources.
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      //  Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error","> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebChromeClient
{

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(MainActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            findViewById(R.id.imageLoading2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MainActivity.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            MainActivity.this.setValue(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);

            if (newProgress >= 100) {
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {
                progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading2).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }

    // You can create external class extends with WebChromeClient
    // Taking WebViewClient as inner class
    // we will define openFileChooser for select file from camera or sdcard


}



@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(webView.canGoBack()) {

        webView.goBack();
    } else {
        // Let the system handle the back button
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


public void setValue(int progress) {
    this.progress.setProgress(progress);

}


}
```

**RegisterActivity.java**

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

// UI elements
EditText txtName;
EditText txtEmail;

// Register button
Button btnRegister;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    //Get Global Controller Class object (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
    final Controller aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    // Check if Internet Connection present
    if (!aController.isConnectingToInternet()) {

        // Internet Connection is not present
        aController.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);

        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Check if GCM configuration is set
    if (Config.YOUR_SERVER_URL == null
            || Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID == null
            || Config.YOUR_SERVER_URL.length() == 0
            || Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID.length() == 0) {

        // GCM sernder id / server url is missing
        aController.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this, "Configuration Error!",
                "Please set your Server URL and GCM Sender ID", false);

        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);

    // Click event on Register button
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Get data from EditText
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String email = txtEmail.getText().toString();

            // Check if user filled the form
            if(name.trim().length() > 0 && email.trim().length() > 0){

                // Launch Main Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                // Registering user on our server
                // Sending registraiton details to MainActivity
                i.putExtra("name", name);
                i.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }else{

                // user doen't filled that data
                aController.showAlertDialog(RegisterActivity.this,
                        "Registration Error!",
                        "Please enter your details",
                        false);
            }
        }
    });
}

}
```

**Confing.java**

```
public interface Config {


// CONSTANTS
static final String YOUR_SERVER_URL ="http://eduapp.in/hello/register.php";

// Google project id
static final String GOOGLE_SENDER_ID = "189074368474";

/**
 * Tag used on log messages.
 */
static final String TAG = "GCM Android Example";

static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION ="com.eduapp.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";

static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";


}
```

**GCMIntentService.java**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

private Controller aController = null;

public GCMIntentService() {
    // Call extended class Constructor GCMBaseIntentService
    super(Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);
}

/**
 * Method called on device registered
 **/
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {

    //Get Global Controller Class object (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
    if(aController == null)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,
            "Your device registred with GCM");
    Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
    aController.register(context, MainActivity.name,
            MainActivity.email, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on device unregistred
 * */
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    if(aController == null)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();
    Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
    aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
    aController.unregister(context, registrationId);
}

/**
 * Method called on Receiving a new message from GCM server
 * */
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if(aController == null)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
    String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

    aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on receiving a deleted message
 * */
@Override
protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {

    if(aController == null)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
    String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
    aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
    // notifies user
    generateNotification(context, message);
}

/**
 * Method called on Error
 * */
@Override
public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {

    if(aController == null)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,
            getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {

    if(aController == null)
        aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    // log message
    Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
    aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,
            getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
                    errorId));
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

/**
 * Create a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
 */
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
   long when2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    b.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(icon)
            .setTicker("Eduapp.in")
            .setContentTitle("New Notification")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentInfo("Eduapp.in");



    //context, title, message, intent,icon, message, when
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());

}

}
```

Comment: use the shared variable for session management in android, it will help you to save username and password. do not directly pull user on register page. use some other activity first and give the options for register and sign in there

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a session to do this. A session will keep your details from your first login, so that when to come back to the app later, the username and password are already saved in the app. These are obviously embedded in the app are not visible to the user.

I would also implement the idea that the user can logout and re-enter his/her credentials on the next use of the app if they wish.

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/) is a great tutorial of how this is implemented.

Hope this helps :)